# Application Targeted for Framework 4.0 works on Framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net

If the user's PC has only Framework 2.0 installed, will Framework 4.0 work?

I installed windows 7 on my other laptop and tried to run my application built on C#, it didn't work. I figured out that my application is targeted for Framework 4.

[image: My Case]

When I ran this app on that laptop, it didn't work.. I wonder why,  i thought that framework is already installed with windows. It's either it has an old Framework version ( like 2.0 ) OR it doesn't have any Framework installed.

Should I change my target to Framework 2.0 in order to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If the user's PC has only Framework 2.0 installed, will Framework 4.0 work?

If the user has only .NET 2.0 installed and you attempt to run an application compiled against .NET 4.0 it won't work.

On the other hand if the user has .NET 4.0 installed and you attempt to run an application compiled against .NET 2.0 this will work.

I am not aware of any forward compatible frameworks. Only backwards compatible. Makes sense?

> Should I change my target to Framework 2.0 in order to make it work?

Yes, if you want to run your application on a computer that has only .NET 2.0 installed.

Comment: Alright Darin! I appreciate your quick and smooth help!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Using the "ClickOnce" setup wizard, you can also embed redistributables (such as .NET 4.0) or provide the user with a download link. That way, when he installs the application, it will also install .NET 4.0.

Comment: Why is it that windows 8 will execute .NET 4.0 and 4.5 assemblies only and not earlier versions unless you install an additional add-on? If you run an assembly with the target framework 3.0 on an out of the box Windows 8 install you will be required to install another package which doesn't make sense considering I always believed .NET to be backwards compatible (as you describe)!